# How to change child, wrapped div width with transition animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How can I animate change of the `width` of `.box` div element after hovering on the `.container`? Transition set to 1s works fine for new background color, but it doesn't for the width of the div. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.container {
  overflow: visible;
}

.container:hover .box {
  width: max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
  background: green;
}

.box {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.box-title {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-title">Some long text that is not visible until you hover over it</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-content is a state, you cannot animate from some xy value to a state.

Comment: Is there any way to fit it to the content somehow, without guessing expected width?

Comment: I'm afraid not.